# Every time I create a module in eclipse it throws an error?

Tags: java, eclipse

[Added a pic of the build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Rm4.png)I have Eclipse version -2019-03 (4.11.0). I also have JDK 12.01., not sure why but I cant make a module in Eclipse, I would make a new java project, name it, then eclipse would prompt me to create a module, the module it automatically named the same name as the project name, I would hit accept then this error -

"Building work space has encountered a problem -Errors occurred during the build.Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Newpro'. java.lang.NullPointerException"

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Lin! Why are you creating a module if you want a project? Also, can you please post the source code you are using?

Comment: Retry it with the current release, 2019-06.

Comment: @Ashish When I create a new project I get a prompt window asking me to name my module. I name the module and the above error occurs.

Comment: I suggest you to try IntelliJ, also the Community Edition (free)... You will never look back! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to 2019-06 Fixed the issue-

You first need to add the new release's repository as follows:
Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites
Click 'Add'
Enter the URL of the new repository (for example, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-06/ ).
Click 'Ok'
Help > Check for Updates
If updates are found, proceed through the install wizard and restart the IDE when prompted. Otherwise, read carefully the error message to find out which component is conflicting and establish your resolution strategy.
Note that the start splash screen may be cached and will not necessarily be updated to the latest version after the IDE is restarted. Performing a full relaunch should display the new version number.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this problem happens when there is a dependency on build path that no longer exists or had its name changed. Check this possibility at:
**Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path**

Comment: I added a screen shot of my java build path